# SSRS URL only links to first entry

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using SSRS to display some data-generated reports. In my database table, I have a cell called user ID. I tried to link it to a URL, but no matter which cell I click when I run my report, it always links to the first userID. This is the expression I used to get the value of the userID.

```
=Fields!userid.Value
```

I have a common beginning and end to the URL, but the unique ID always refers to the first cell in the column. Please help!

Comment: You need to provide more context/detail for your situation.   What groups are you using in your tablix/table, what is the script that generates your URL to name a few? Have you tried to output `Fields!userid.Value` in a another column ?

Comment: So there really isnt a script generating the URL. It's just a fixed beginning + user ID + fixed ending. The userID comes from a query I did in SQL and so my table has 3 columns: Name, Username, UserID. They all show up when I run the report, but when I tried associated each UserID to a link, all the links use the first row's UserID instead of their own individual ones. Also, I did output `Fields!userid.Value` in another column and it only outputs the first entry's UserID

Comment: Where is your link? Is it not in a table? If it's just a text box on it's own, it will take the first value of the dataset since it wouldn't otherwise know which to use. Normally you would have an extra column **in a table** with the Action (go to URL) using the UserID field as you described. This way it would use the UserID associated with the record that's clicked on.

Comment: Please excuse my lack of skill with this program it is my first time using it. I believe my data is in a table because I created it by inserting a table and dragging a dataset into one of the columns. If this isn't the proper way to do it then please tell me the correct method as I really need this to work. Also, I dont know if this will help, but this is the expression that I'm using for the action.`=Parameters!URL_START.Value & Parameters!userid.Value & Parameters!URL_END.Value`

Comment: Your action should refer to your **field** not your **parameter**.  

`=Parameters!URL_START.Value & Fields!userid.Value & Parameters!URL_END.Value`